# Sphere inside of a Sphere

Tags: probability, geometry, circles, spheres

I have a very interesting question.

I am given the fact that people like cookies the most when the ratio of cookie dough to chocolate is 1:1. The cookie is first placed on a sheet and has a diameter of one. The cookie is then covered in a layer of chocolate that's volume most match that of the cookie dough. It is a sphere inside of another sphere, with them having matching volumes.

Please answer in fractional form
Thanks!

Comment: Where is the sphere? Do you mean a circle? Also, what do you want the fractional form of?

Comment: This sounds like a challenge for [Claire Saffitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claire_Saffitz).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If the inner sphere of dough has radius $r$ and when the outer shell of choclate has radius $R$ ... and we require the volume of dough & chocolate to be equal then
\begin{eqnarray*}
2 \frac{4 \pi r^3}{3} =  \frac{4 \pi R^3}{3}.
\end{eqnarray*}
So we require the ratio $R/r = \sqrt[3]{2}=1.2599 \cdots$. So a good approximation would be $ \frac{5}{4}$.

In other words if your ball of dough is $4$ units then when it is covered in chocolate make the radius increase to $5$ units.

Note that we rounded $1.2599$ down to $1.25$ so there will be slightly less chocolate ... so I would advise you to put an extra smidge of chocolate on in order to remedy this ... you can't put too much chocolate on your cookies!

Answer (score 4):

Consider cookie as $3D$ object. So if corresponding $1D$ size of cookie + chocolate is $a > 1$ where $1D$ size of cookie is $1$, then $3D$ size of cookie with chocolate will be $a^3$.

Now, you have

$$ \frac{cookie + chocolate}{cookie} = \frac{a^3}{1} = 2 $$

Or

$$ a^3 = 2 $$

Therefore chocolate addition to diameter must be $\sqrt[3]{2} - 1$